# jQuery FadeIn, FadeOut spamming bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have typed some code to fade in and out some divs including a navigator.

I've noticed a bug when you click the navigator fast and try to change between divs very fast by spamming the buttons, the div's will be bugged and if you will inspect the code, you will see that the divs are fading in up to 0.5 opacity, or sometimes even 0.12 and fades out to 0.0 up to 0.09 or something like that.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var currentDiv = $("#fading_divs div:first");
        currentDiv.css("display","block");
    var divN = $("#fading_divs div").length;
    var fadeInterval;


    for(i=0; i<divN; i++){   
      $('<span />').text(i+1).appendTo('#fade_nav');   
    }

    $('#fade_nav span').eq(0).addClass('active');


    $('#fade_nav span').click(function(){ 
        clearInterval(fadeInterval);
        $('#fade_nav span').removeClass('active').eq( $(this).index() ).addClass('active');    

        currentDiv.fadeOut({duration:1000,queue:false});
        currentDiv = $("#fading_divs div").eq( $(this).index() );
        currentDiv.fadeIn({duration:1000,queue:false});

        anim();


    });

    function anim() {
        fadeInterval = setInterval(function(){
            currentDiv.fadeOut({duration:1000,queue:false});

            if(currentDiv.next().length)
                currentDiv = currentDiv.next(); 

            else
                currentDiv = currentDiv.siblings().first();

            $('#fade_nav span').removeClass('active').eq( currentDiv.index() ).addClass('active');
            currentDiv.fadeIn({duration:1000,queue:false});
        }, 4000);
    }

    anim();

});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5PfE/

try to spam the nav buttons until you will see that the divs are barely fading in or out.

Any suggestion about how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually solve issues like that:

1. Add a class to your #fade_nav span of "activated"
2. Use $('.activated').live('click', function (event) { // }); to start your function
3. Within that function, first remove the activated class from #fade_nav. This will prevent the buttons from being clickable during your animation.
4. At the end of the function, add the .activated class back on so the buttons are clickable once more.

Comment: If possible, please provide me a jsfiddle, I lost you a little bit :/ BTW `.live()` is deprecated and removed since 1.9

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time at the moment. I think your problem is you are starting a new animation before an old one has finished. So if you can disable your buttons during the animation, you can avoid the problem.